Using XSLT to Iterate and Transform XML to Simple Text
I am a beginner and still learning in XSLT. I have a simple xml code below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order id="1021">
    <items>
        <item code="11">
            <quantity>2</quantity
            <price>50</price>
        </item>
        <item code="21">
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <price>250</price>
        </item>
        <item code="13">
            <quantity>4</quantity>
            <price>100</price>
        </item>
    </items>
    <status>3</status>
</order>

And I want to write an XSLT script which will convert it into a simple text array which contains all item codes. For example, the above xml should be converted as: [11,21,13]
I have written the following XSLT Code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Template to match the root 'order' element -->
    <xsl:template match="/order">
        <!-- Start bracket for the array -->
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
        <!-- Iterate over each item -->
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <!-- Output the code attribute -->
            <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
            <!-- If not the last item, add a comma and space -->
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- End bracket for the array -->
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

I am facing the problem in iterating over all items. I only get the code of the first item in output: [11]
Where as I am expecting the codes of all items like: [11,21,13]
Kindly let me know if anyone can spot a mistake in my XSLT code. I have tried asking chatgpt for it but it was not much of a help.

There is no mistake in your XSLT and it produces the expected result (except there are spaces after the commas) - provided you add the missing > in the input XML. How are you testing this?

I am testing this on an online compiler of w3 schools and also tried a python program which is transforming it. Both of them give the same output

Please edit the question and show the complete Python code allowing us to reproduce the alleged result [11]. I with code like https://gist.github.com/martin-honnen/baa79449b27317d33e697a15ee2d67f9 certainly get the result [11, 21, 13].

You must be using a different code in your tests.

I see that you are using XSLT 1.0 (circa 1999). Would it be possible for you to start using XSLT 2.0 or 3.0? It will make your task much easier.

@YitzhakKhabinsky Your comment could be interpreted as suggesting that the problem is caused by some flaw in XSLT 1.0. Which is of course not true.

The OP mentioned "I am a beginner and still learning in XSLT". It is better to start learning XSLT with version better than 1.0

@YitzhakKhabinsky Possibly, but it has nothing to do with the question. It would be better to postpone your advice until after the current problem has been solved.

I made a dumb mistake in the XML code where I am missing the > as spotted by @michael.hor257k

2</quantity
50


But any conforming processor would have thrown an error instead of the result you claim you got.

Your XSLT 1.0 is perfectly working.
For comparison, please see below how it is much easier to implement in XSLT 2.0 and later versions.
In XSLT 2.0, <xsl:value-of> was enhanced, and has a separator attribute.
XSLT, 2nd Edition by Doug Tidwell

XSLT 1.0 became a W3C recommendation in November 1999.
XSLT 2.0 became a W3C recommendation in January 2007.
XSLT 3.0 became a W3C recommendation in June 2017.

For the reference: XSLT
Input XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order id="1021">
    <items>
        <item code="11">
            <quantity>2</quantity>
            <price>50</price>
        </item>
        <item code="21">
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <price>250</price>
        </item>
        <item code="13">
            <quantity>4</quantity>
            <price>100</price>
        </item>
    </items>
    <status>3</status>
</order>

XSLT 1.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Template to match the root 'order' element -->
    <xsl:template match="/order">
        <!-- Start bracket for the array -->
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
        <!-- Iterate over each item -->
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <!-- Output the code attribute -->
            <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
            <!-- If not the last item, add a comma and space -->
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- End bracket for the array -->
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

XSLT 2.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="order/items/item/@code"
                      separator=", "/>
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output
[11, 21, 13]


Since you are so enthusiastic about staying up to date with the latest version of XSLT, you could have gone to XSLT 3.0 to produce the wanted result using only <xsl:sequence select="array{/order/items/item/number(@code)}"/>.  But all of this has still nothing to do with the question.

@michael.hor257k, I totally agree with you. Let's wait for the OP feedback.

Thank you for the reference of XSLT 2.0 and also for XSLT 3.0 @michael.hor257k I believe the language is made easier with new versions. However, for my course, we are supposed to learn and work on XSLT 1.0. Therefore, I was trying to explore and practice that.

You wrote the XML code correctly by adding the missing > which was causing the issue in the output.
